# Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(GestionGeneralModule)

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngxs

Hello I am trying to list a table with the ResumenService service but I get the following error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(GestionGeneralModule)[NgxsFeatureModule ->
> GestionGeneralSolState -> ResumenService -> ResumenService ->
> ResumenService -> ResumenService -> ResumenService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for ResumenService! NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(GestionGeneralModule)[NgxsFeatureModule ->
> GestionGeneralSolState -> ResumenService -> ResumenService ->
> ResumenService -> ResumenService -> ResumenService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for ResumenService!

general.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { GeneralRoutingModule } from './general-routing.module';
        import { GeneralService } from './services/general.service';
        import { ResumenService } from './services/resumen.service';
  
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [],
          imports: [
            GeneralRoutingModule,
            HttpClientModule
            
          ],
          providers: [
            GeneralService,
            ResumenService,
          ]
        })
        export class GeneralModule { }
```

resumen.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ConvertObjectToGetParams, IDataGridPageRequest } from "shared";
import { CORE_FUNCTIONS, IPaginationResponse, IServerResponse } from '@app/core';
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

@Injectable()
export class ResumenService {
    private url = `${environment.baseUrlAPI}/api/resumen`;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    ListarSolDocumentosControl = (idEvento: number) => {
        const params = ConvertObjectToGetParams({ idEvento });
        return this.http.get<IServerResponse<any[]>>(
            `${this.url}/SolDocumentosControl`, { params }
        );
    };

    guardarResumen = (idEvento: number, data: any, archivo: any) => {

        const formData = CORE_FUNCTIONS.jsonToFormData({
            ...data,
            archivo
        });

        return this.http.post<IServerResponse<any[]>>(
            `${this.url}/DocumentosControl/${idEvento}`, formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'Upload-File' } }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using angular version 6+, then add `{providedIn: 'root' }` inside your `@Injectable()` decorator and remove `ResumenService` from GeneralModule.

Answer (score 1):

In ResumenService replace your `@Injectable` for this:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' // It will inject this provider at the root level of the application so it can be accessed anywhere.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ResumenService` into GestionGeneralSolState in GestionGeneralModule, but you only provide this service in GeneralModule. Please double check in GestionGeneralModule whether you have declared ResumenService or not